# Open Activity depending on TextView value

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have button and TextView in MainActivity and I have another three activities example (one, two, three, four) so I want when text is 'hi' in TextView then when I click the button the one Activity will be open and with text equals to 'hello' it open the two Activity, with 'nice' text Activity three and with 'thanks' text activity four.java will be opened please help me someone please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String s = tv.getText().toString();

        if (s.equals("hi")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, One.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (s.equals("hello")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Two.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (s.equals("nice")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Three.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        if (s.equals("thanks")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Four.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```